# как вывести количество объектов на одного user mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

в таблице objektos присваиваться к каждой записи user_id 
то есть кто добавил эту запись.
мне нужно что бы возле каждого пользователя выводилось количество записей на user_id то есть сколько каждый добавил записей.

есть такой код, но она не работает, теряются все результаты с остальными значениями там где я вывожу

```
   select  u.* ,
      (select count(*) from objektos o GROUP BY user_id) as entry_count
     from users u 
order by u.id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.* ,
ifnull(c.cnt, 0) as entry_count
from users u 
left join (select count(*) as cnt, o.user_id from objektos o GROUP BY user_id) as c ON u.id = c.user_id
order by u.id desc
```